# How to use BindPose for character customization in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a character customization feature for my game in Unity, where I want to allow players to modify the appearance of their characters on the run, such as adjusting the shoulder width, height, etc. I've read that using **`BindPose`** can be a good approach for this, as it allows for dynamic changes without affecting the animations.

This is my current attempt using bindpose to morph the bone. Basically, I am struggling with the `BindPose` code inside the `switch`. Some bones need to scale up or down, some bones need to move their positions. I am successful in changing the bone without animations. But with anims, the scale and position will be reset by Unity. So my code stops working and I need `BindPose` to solve this problem. I googled and found some possible solutions and I have put potential solutions in the commented code. But my code leads to an extremely distorted character as you can see from the picture below. `BindPose` solution need good math but I am really poor at it :(

What's the correct way to implement this? Thank you in advance for your help!

```
private void SetBone(SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer, BodyParameterType paramType, float value)
{
    if (!skinnedMeshRenderer)
    {
        return;
    }
    BoneChangeType boneChangeType = paramType.BoneChangeType;
    if (boneChangeType == BoneChangeType.None)
    {
        return;
    }
    Mesh mesh = skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh;
    Matrix4x4[] bindPoses = mesh.bindposes;
    Transform[] bones = skinnedMeshRenderer.bones;

    BoneChangeDimension dimension = paramType.BoneChangeDimension;
    int boneChangeDirection = paramType.BoneChangeDirection;
    float actualMinValue = paramType.GetActualMinValue(gender);
    float currentValue = BodyParams.GetValue(paramType);
    List<string> leftRight = paramType.HasLeftRight ? new (){"l", "r"} : new () {""};
    foreach (var boneName in paramType.Bones)
    {
        foreach (var direction in leftRight)
        {
            string boneRealName = direction + boneName;
            Transform bone = transform.FindChildOfName(boneRealName);
            if (!bone)
            {
                Debug.Log("bone not found: " + boneRealName);
                continue;
            }
            int boneIndex = bones.FindIndex(bone);
            if (boneIndex == -1)
            {
                Debug.Log("bone index not found: " + boneRealName);
                continue;
            }
            Vector3 scale = bone.localScale;
            Vector3 position = bone.localPosition;
            switch (boneChangeType)
            {
                case BoneChangeType.Scale:
                    scale[(int)dimension] = value / actualMinValue;
                    bone.localScale = scale;
                    // bindPoses[boneIndex] = Matrix4x4.Scale(position) * bindPoses[boneIndex];
                    // Vector3 vertexPositionInBone_20 = (BN_20.transform.worldToLocalMatrix * mesh.transform.localToWorldMatrix).MultiplyPoint3x4(vertex.transform.localPosition);
                    // vertex.transform.position = bone.transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertexPositionInBone_20);
                    break;
                case BoneChangeType.Position:
                    int leftRightDirection = dimension == BoneChangeDimension.X && direction == "r" ? -1 : 1;
                    float diff = value - currentValue;
                    float newValue = leftRightDirection * boneChangeDirection * diff / GlobalData.CmPerDistance;
                    position[(int)dimension] += newValue;
                    Matrix4x4 oldLocation = bone.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
                    bone.localPosition = position;
                    bindPoses[boneIndex] = oldLocation * bone.worldToLocalMatrix * oldLocation * transform.localToWorldMatrix;
                    // Matrix4x4 newBindPose = oldBone.transform.worldToLocalMatrix * newBone.transform.localToWorldMatrix * oldBone.transform.worldToLocalMatrix * mesh.localToWorldMatrix;
                    break;
            }
            if (_bodyParameterHandlers.TryGetValue(paramType, out BodyParameterHandler handler))
            {
                handler.HandleAttachment(new (value, currentValue));
            }
        }
    }
    _bodyMesh.bindposes = bindPoses;
}
```

[image]